# Lock a single access variable for parallel threads in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, plinq

Hello i have this code

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
            queue.Add(0);            
            var producers = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
                .Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
                    {

                    Enumerable.Range(1, queue.Count)
                            .ToList().ForEach(i =>
                                {

                                    lock (queue)
                                        {
                                            if (!queue.Contains(i))
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("Thread" + Task.CurrentId.ToString());
                                                queue.Add(i);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                                });

                    }))
                 .ToArray();

            Task.WaitAll(producers);
            queue.CompleteAdding();

                foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {                    
                        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());               
                }
```

But i need each time that a single thread ads something to the queue.Add(i) the 
 Enumerable.Range(1, queue.Count) to be inceased so that the code executes until there are no more items to be added to the queue. I hope you understand the question.
In other words i need this action to run infinitely untill i tell it to stop.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The count is only taken once in the `Enumerate.Range`, so it is not observing the changes that are later done by the code in `ForEach`. Maybe if you tell us what you trying to do we can provide better solution. I cannot see clearly why to use blocking collection and tasks and locks all together.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine what you're trying to do here. As it exists, the code will always generate a list of one item. That is, `Enumerable.Rang(1, queue.Count).ToList()` creates a new list that contains what's in the queue. The list is never updated. Also, you might consider using something other than a queue if there can be many items. That `queue.Contains` is an O(N) operation, so this is going to execute with the alacrity of a bubble sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m sorry to say, but I can´t understand your motives for writing something like that without further explaination :(

Is the following code useful to you in any way? Because I don´t think it is :P

```
        int n = 2;

        Task[] producers = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(_ => 
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (queue.Count < n)
                    {
                        lock (queue)
                        {
                            if (!queue.Contains(n))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Thread" + Task. CurrentId);
                                queue.Add(n);

                                Interlocked.Increment(ref n);
                            }
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }))
            .ToArray();
```

I mean, it will just go on and on. It´s like a reeeeeeaaallllyyy strange way of just adding numbers to a List

Please explain you objective and we might be able to help you.

Comment: lol i think yes this could work, i will test it when i get home, it's hard for me to explain the problem in simple terms, i will return later on :P thanx

Comment: Hi @Johan, I would say this contribution is not really a helpful, constructive and problem solving answer. Please keep in mind you are not just answering one person, but leaving your contribution in Q&A forever. If the author of question was not able to express himself well enough you still have a possibility to help him by asking question in comments or editing the question.

Comment: @achitaka-san, that is correct. It seems to be a matter of views. I guess I can´t really determine the type if contribution I produced, but it seems themhz was happy with the answer anyway.

Comment: I Dont think that my previuse answer was irelevant , The producer consumer pattern is applied in spider situations were many producers spiders are creating links and consumer spiders are useing the links to visit them. I asked the questin in simple terms, and everyone wanted to know what i am up to, so i gave them all my code to see what and how I applied there answeres in my Code. I am sorry if the question is not clear, but now i think it is clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I see, what you need is a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) which came with .NET 4.0.
It allows to implement the Producer-Consumer pattern.

Multiple threads or tasks can add items to the collection concurrently. Multiple consumers can remove items concurrently, and if the collection becomes empty, the consuming threads will block and wait until a producer adds an item. Over and over again ...

... until a special method will be called by producer to identify the end, saying consumer "Hey, stop waiting there - nothing will come anymore!".

I am not posting code samples, because there are some under given link. You can find much more if you just google for **Producer-Consumer pattern** and/or `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: thanx achitaka-san, I think you are right, I need to understand the Producer-Consumer pattern in order to make this work.